# CDE Tables with changing column number

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

We have problem with table component in our dashboard. To make lazy loading we are using the same table component, and fill it with data from our mdx queries. The problem is, that each query can return different number of columns and table fixes on one size at the moment of first loading of data. I can reload data, but only if the columns count is identical.

To put it simple, how can I change number of columns in already initialized table?

Answer (score 1):

put this function in to Pre Execute

```
function f() {
        this.chartDefinition.colHeaders = [];
        this.chartDefinition.colTypes = [];
        this.chartDefinition.colFormats = [];        
}
```

hope this help